# Combine two array into 1 array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 1D array:

`a=[1 2 3]
b=[4 5 6]`

How to combine them to an array c like this?

`c=[[1 4]
   [2 5]
   [3 6]]`

Comment: Search for "Stacking NumPy arrays".

Comment: Do you have lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: stacking or zip will return an array of list, I don't want to have a list (e.g. [(1, 4), ...]

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

np.vstack((a,b)).T
```

**Result** :

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Comment: `np.hstack` gives `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`

Answer (score 0):

You can zip them together

python2

```
c = zip(a,b)
```

python3

```
c = list(zip(a,b))
```

Both pythons if you want a list in list

```
c = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: `zip(a,b) ` is already a `list`

Comment: True for python2, i made this clear in my solution :-)

Comment: But still, he/she wants a list of `list` and not a list of `tuples` which is the case with `zip`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
c = [[a[i], b[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```

My output:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```